# Cannot connect via SSH even though ping works

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vmware, ping

I want to connect Ubuntu (on VMware Workstation 11.0) via SSH (from Windows 10) but I can't:

- Ubuntu (on VMware) and Windows can ping each other;
- SSH server is on (systemctl status ssh .... activate);
- Two days ago I had no problems and could connect correctly with PuTTY, but I don't know what happened to make it stop working.

Notes:

1. I have six Linuxes on my VMware (several Ubuntus and CentOSes), and I can't connect to any of them. Up until two days ago I could connect to all of them.
2. All the Linuxes on VMware can connect each other via SSH, but Windows 10 can't connect to any of them.

Comment: Are you using VMWare ESX or Workstation/Player?

Comment: I' m using VMware Workstation.

Comment: What kind of error you got when you try to connect - timeout or something else?

Comment: The error is connection timeout.

Comment: @Saha If you are using VMWare Workstation then edit your question to make that clear.  Be sure you indicate which version your using.  You do understand that ping packets and ssh packets are sent on entirely different ports, right?

Comment: Maybe the firewall on the host is blocking connections?

Comment: Finally I found that ESET antivirus had caused problems and I was forced delete it! Now ssh connection is OK.